# Cyrilic characters in \label and \ref in pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, labels, ref, russian

I want to write `\label` and `\ref` with Cyrillic(Russian) characters in pdflatex. `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` in preamble.

I tried `\label{\detokenize{}}`, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 

\begin{document}
    \section{Раздел}
    \label{\detokenize{Ссылка_на_раздел}}
     Русский текст \ref{\detokenize{Ссылка_на_раздел}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a complete but minimal example document with your attempts?

Comment: With pdfLaTeX I would only use safe ASCII characters in labels. Sometimes certain non-ASCII characters may work by accident, but that is not at all guaranteed (e.g. `\section{Ä}\label{ä}\ref{ä}` works for me, but `\section{ß}\label{ß}\ref{ß}` fails spectacularly). If you want non-ASCII labels you need to use a full Unicode engine such as XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sort of works if you do a “double detokenization”:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \section{Раздел}
    \label{\detokenize{\detokenize{Ссылка_на_раздел}}}
     Русский текст \ref{\detokenize{Ссылка_на_раздел}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the problem? With a single `\detokenize`, the label is written as is in the `.aux` file, but when the `.aux` file is read in, the Cyrillic characters are no longer “detokenized” and it's impossible to form control sequence names with them.

You see you can, is it worth the pain? I don't think so. On the other hand, Unicode TeX engines such as XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX have no problem with those characters in labels.

Comment: It works as I expected, unless `hyperref` package destroys all success even it placed before or after redefined `\label`  and `\ref`

Comment: @ShalomAlecheim `hyperref` does further massaging, so it's kind of expected that it doesn't work.